# Get the current array key inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, forms, foreach

Ok so, I am building something for my employer for them to input products, they have very specific requirements. I have a form with dynamically generated fields like so...
(obviously not the exact code to follow but the examples are identical conceptually)

```
<input type="text" name="attribute[20]"> inputted value = height
<input type="text" name="attribute[27]"> inputted value = width
```

the numbers are generated based on things in the database, so 20 would correlate to "width" 27 would correlate to "height" for example.

So once the user enters the values I need those values to go into a database...or in the test, echo out.

```
foreach ($_POST['attribute'] as $attributes){
echo key($attributes).' '.$attributes.'<br>';
}
```

So that should output...

```
20 height value<br>
27 width value
```

but instead it outputs

```
&nbsp;height value<br>
&nbsp;width value
```

What is going on? I have something similar...but slightly different as the defined numbers can have more than one input....which works perfectly.

```
<input type="text" name="option[][20]"> inputted value = option 1
<input type="text" name="option[][20]"> inputted value = option 2
<input type="text" name="option[][27]"> inputted value = option 1

foreach ($_POST['option'] as $options){
echo key($options).' ';
foreach ($options as $option){
echo $option.'<br>';
}
```

which outputs perfectly...

```
20 option 1<br>
20 option 2<br>
27 option 1
```

I don't understand why the more complex one works and the simpler one doesn't, am I missing something obvious? I am aware I have a somewhat unorthodox method of coding in comparison to some, but it is what it is lol. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Var dump as requested

array(22) { ["pID"]=> string(12) "test product" ["pPrice"]=> string(0) "" ["pName"]=> string(0) "" ["pRRP"]=> string(0) "" ["pPostSize"]=> string(0) "" ["pOurPrice"]=> string(0) "" ["pEstDelivery"]=> string(0) "" ["pWeight"]=> string(0) "" ["pEAN"]=> string(0) "" ["pOrder"]=> string(0) "" ["pStock"]=> string(0) "" ["pManufacturer"]=> string(0) "" ["pType"]=> string(13) "Shower Valves" ["pRange"]=> string(0) "" ["cat"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "72" [1]=> string(2) "23" } ["attribute"]=> array(2) { [***0***]=> string(5) "***width***" [1]=> string(6) "height" } ["option"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { [**11**]=> string(6) "**works1**" } [1]=> array(1) { [**10**]=> string(6) "**works1**" } [2]=> array(1) { [**10**]=> string(6) "**works2**" } } ["pLongdescription"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_description"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_keyword"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_title"]=> string(0) "" ["action"]=> string(6) "create" }

the bold parts, are the parts that successfully come out in my second example. but the bold italic as you can see, returns 0 instead of the 20 that is actually in the form name value.

Comment: Care to format your dump a little? It is unreadable! (Insert some enters, indent sub-arrays, etc.)

Comment: No need, works fine thanks to the tips received from Jim and yourself, albeit your's being condescending in tone. But thank you nonetheless.

Comment: Glad we could have helped you in making you understand it better!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="attribute[20]"> inputted value = height
<input type="text" name="attribute[27]"> inputted value = width

foreach ($_POST['attribute'] as $attributes){
    echo key($attributes).' '.$attributes.'<br>';
}
```

Note here that you are looping over the attribute array in post. $attributes is the value for each field (and is  therefore not an array.

Instead of using `key()` try:

```
foreach ($_POST['attribute'] as $attributeKey => $attributes){
    echo $attributeKey.' '.$attributes.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not, I tried similar earlier, and again just now incase i did something wrong earlier. that outputs...

0 value<br>
1 value

...instead of....

20 value<br>
27 value

:(

Answer (score 2):

According to the PHP [documentation of key()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php):

> The **key()** function simply returns the key of the array element that's currently being pointed to by the internal pointer. It does not move the pointer in any way. If the internal pointer points beyond the end of the elements list or the array is empty, **key()** returns **NULL**.

The documentation (and example) shows that you need to provide the actual array as parameter, where you are using the value.

So use something like this:

```
$yourArray = $_POST['attribute'];
foreach ($yourArray as $attributes){
  echo key($yourArray).' '.$attributes.'<br>';
}
```

Even though you notice that are aware that you have a 'somewhat unorthodox method of coding in comparison to some', it would be much better to use the `foreach`-loop in this way:

```
foreach ($_POST['attribute'] as $attributeKey => $attributes){
    echo $attributeKey.' '.$attributes.'<br>';
}
```

as the `key()` method seems a bit 'dodgy' to me (being dependent on internal pointers).

Check out the [foreach documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for more information on this use.

Comment: Nope, that outputs 0 value1 0 value2. As said, I use key() in my second example and it works perfectly?! Very confusing.

Comment: Your second example works by accident, probably because you use the `$options` array in your second `foreach`-loop... :) As stated in the documentation you need to provide the *array* as the `key()` parameter and you provide the array *values* as parameter.

Comment: But i tried that and it still doesn't do what I want lol. The second example, may well be working by accident, but it does exactly what I want ;)

Comment: the `echo key($options)` in your second 'working' example, should show the keys of the first array dimension. Which are not set and should return an empty value. Instead they *luckily* show the values of the second dimension of your 2d array because you use `$options` in your second `foreach` loop... If you are happy with this result, be my guest... :) But do not expect that this type of 'luck' works for your first code example!

Comment: Ah i see what you mean. I actually tried using a 2d approach to mimick the working example and it did exactly what you described, returned empty values.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so, I have fixed it, with the help of you guys and the realization that i had been a little stupid and only edited the static part of the form to incorporate the dynamic key and not the ajax generated part which overwrites it.

```
foreach ($_POST['attribute'] as $key => $attributes){
echo $key.'+'.$attributes.'<br>';
}
```

Works perfectly. thanks for the tips guys.