# PHP function Get the current key and value inside an array, array to string conversion error

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have the following function which gets some data from DB table.

Now I realize this question must have been asked many times before but I refer you to this link which is the top result for problem Im having. [Get the current key and value inside an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850956/get-the-current-array-key-inside-foreach)

When I call my function and do a `var_dump(LoadBoxes())` all is well no problems, thus my function is working correctly as can be seen from the image below:

[image]

However when I try to get the array keys and values as pointed out by top linked question I get the following error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\beta\xxxx\xxxx_letsGo.php on line 25 0 Array

So clearly I must be doing something wrong any help appreciated, code follows:

```
function LoadBoxes()
{
    $db = DB::getInstance();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM beta_letsgocontent";
    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->execute();
    $boxes = $stmnt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($boxes as $box) {
        $data[] = array(
            'LowHeadline' => $box['lowHeadline'],
            'MediumHeadline' => $box['mediumHeadline'],
            'HighHeadline' => $box['highHeadline'],
            'Low' => $box['BoxLow'],
            'Medium' => $box['BoxMedium'],
            'High' => $box['BoxHigh']);
    }
    return $data;
//call function
$boxesInfo = LoadBoxes(); 
foreach($boxesInfo as $arrayKey => $info) {
    echo $arrayKey.' '.$info;
}
```

Ive tried using `LoadBoxes()` function instead of assigning it to variable `$boxesInfo[]` inside foreach loop, same result. Ive pretty much tried everything to best of my knowledge any help appreciated.

**Additional Info**

It is only when I explicitly call the array key inside foreach() that I get result back like such:

```
foreach($boxesInfo as $arrayKey => $info) {
        echo $boxesInfo['LowHeadline']  // returns LOW RISK 
    }
```

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind, however, comment is out of scope, since it is not a solution to my problem unless it is and im not getting it.... in which case would you care to expand

Comment: You had tagged it with OOP, which made it "in scope". Also, you might notice that this is not an answer.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee The top comment is completely unrelated

Comment: @tereško ok no need to be rude though I tagged it with OOP since I first used it in a class and then for testing purposes moved it outside a class. You are clearly the much much much more experienced and better programmer however no need to be a jerk -- we all need to start learning somewhere. I tried stating my problem as best I could, and that in my opinion is what this site is all about, help and learn

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yeah I appreciate that and Im not arguing but why not use that energy to rather help guide me in correct direction....anyway thats just my thought process....what I would do if I could help someone. But yeah totally out of scope. Just looking for some help and or advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `[]` in `$boxesInfo[] = LoadBoxes();` Your function `LoadBoxes()` returns an array of boxinfo, and you assign that to an array. So the loop just sees an array with one element, which is itself another array. If you change the line to `$boxesInfo = LoadBoxes();` you should get the expected result.

On second thought, `loadBoxes()` returns an array of boxes, which are themselves arrays, so you would need nested loops to get the info of all boxes:

```
foreach($boxesInfo as $box) {
    foreach($box as $arrayKey => $info) {
        echo $arrayKey.' '.$info;
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives the same error message when I change it. I reallty dont know why im having such a hard time on what should be something simple been stuck for 2-hours now. I updated question accordingly to your solution since it still gives same problem

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee I already realised that, so I updated my answer.

Comment: Nailed it Thank you very much, for your help I'll figure it out from here

Comment: I just figured out my real problem inside foreach of function I should not have placed [] next to $data since I already said $data = array() my bad, but very well thought out sir

Comment: If you remove the `[]` after `$data`, you won't get more than one result from `loadBoxes()`. You should test what happens when the table contains more than one row (or no rows at all, for that matter).